# Removing zero from time

Tags: php

when getting a time from the database I get a time result with zeros. I want to delete all unnecessary zeros in such a way that only the numbers for hours and minutes are left.

```
00:03:56 --> 3:56
01:45:11 --> 1:45:11
00:00:24 --> 0:24
```

Is there any function that formats the time in this way ?. I was looking at php.net and found nothing about it.

**SOLVED**

```
function get_duration($time){
    list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $time);
    if ($h==00){
        $h = '';
        if (substr($m, 0, 1)==0){
            $m = substr($m, 1, 1).':';
        }else{
            $m.= ':';
        }
    }else{
        if (substr($h, 0, 1)==0){
            $h = substr($h, 1, 1).':';
        }
        $m.=':';
    }
    return $h.$m.$s;                      
}

echo get_duration('00:03:56');
//return 3:56
```

Comment: _I was looking at php.net and found nothing about it._ Really?http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: So what should `00:24:00` and `03:56:00` produce?

Comment: AbraCadaver in php.net has no option to display time without zeros. MonkeyZeus 00:00:24 to 0:24 and 00:03:56 to 3:56

Comment: @urbmake That's not what I asked.

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't do exactly what you're wanting, but it's easy enough to make.  Here's a quick example.

```
// $time = "00:03:16"
$time = date("H:i:s", strtotime("2018-05-21 00:03:16"));

// This Outputs: 3:16
echo formatTime($time);

/*
 * Our formatting function.
 */

function formatTime($time)
{
    list($h, $m, $s) = explode(":", $time);
    return ((int) $h > 0 ? (int) $h . ":" : "") . (int) $m . ":" . (int) $s;
}
```

I do want to warn you that you're going to make it confusing for visitors if this is going to be viewed by anyone but yourself.  Showing minutes and seconds is going to look like it's hours and minutes unless you're doing a countdown timer of some sort that would update often enough to show that it's seconds.

Comment: I have a saved file duration in the database and I want to display the time in this way